# What are the additional chemicals required to make polyurethane foam more viscoelastic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chemical-formula

I am currently experimenting with polyurethane forms for a science and research project I am working on. I need to make the polyurethane foam more viscoelastic, almost like memory foam. I am unable to proceed and would be great if I could get some guidance.